# ASP Core Identity - Unit test In Memory Error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2017, in-memory-database

I am trying to unit test a project of mine which uses ASP identity (EF core) within VS2017.

The issue I have is when I'm creating my DB context using EF cores in memory it blows up with the following Error -

> Message: System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I'm using the following nuget packages

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore - 1.1.2
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory - 1.1.2

Rest are default xunit packages you get when creating the project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, spend many hours trying to work out whats going wrong :/

This is the Unit Test Code:

```
public class TestDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public TestDbContext(DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
}

[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>();

    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();

    var context = new TestDbContext(builder.Options);
}
```

Comment: how are you trying to create the mocked EF context and dbsets? are you using a mocking framework like Moq? and do you have some sample code?

Comment: sorry, just saw example project, I'll have a quick look and see if anything pops at me

Comment: The sample works fine for me. I don't think I did anything special either.This is what I did, downloaded it, checked that there was nothing malicious :P , ran Nuget restore, opened command line and typed in dotnet restore, ran the unit test, got a contect back

Comment: Put the relevant code in your question.

Comment: this is a screenshot of everything working. ignore the nested classes, it's just a test so it doesn't really matter.
http://imgur.com/a/632LC

Comment: I think you have a dependency issue. Your exception indicates a library is trying to load version 1.1.0 however I see your NuGet package points to  Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions version 1.1.1

Comment: this is what i get (i also did dotnet restore before trying it again) http://i.imgur.com/JvNg7u2.png

Comment: I think I might know what's up. :) I sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to latest version of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` solves the problem.

`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.3.0" />`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my observations and some research I think this is related to the XUnit test runner. Here is my working logic.

All assemblies in the ops repository with a dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` reference version 1.1.1 (this is validated by manually looking through dependencies under references and by checking all output DLLs after building).

Running the test using ReSharpers test runner, everything works okay.
[image]

Running the test using the NuGet packet managed `xunit.runner.visualstudio` throws the ops exception... Something is trying to load `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` version 1.1.0 but only when run using the `xunit.runner.visualstudio`
[image]

Doing a bit of research this seems like it's been an issue with the test runner before, however the commonly accepted solution of installing NuGet package `Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions` and or `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` neither seem to work (separately or in conjunction with eachother)

The current solution to get this running in the unit test... Downgrade EF so that the highest dependency to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` is to version 1.1.0

The test worked using the native test runner once I downgraded all the EF libraries to version 1.1.1 (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` version 1.1.1 depends on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` version 1.1.0) and deleted all the output DLLs of version 1.1.1 (I had to delete these manually, a clean didn't seem to remove them)
[image]

I know the op probably doesn't want to downgrade, but hopefully this gives some insight into why the exception is being thrown and helps determine the next best course of action.

EDIT:
I tried adding binding redirects to the `.csproj` file as below, But this still does not work.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks Joe, this works for me, im sure (hope) V2 will fix it so i wont have to be on an old version for long :P

Comment: I'll update the answer too, but just FYI it looks like you can use EF version 1.1.1 as the dependency on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` is still 1.1.0. This way you're only one minor release behind.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is getting tracked in vstest GitHub repo : https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/936